# IBM CLOUD function action took too long to respond in IBM watson chat dialog

Tags: ibm-watson

[image]

Hi, I am creating a chatbot. I developed a IBM cloud function(action) in IBM.

This is the action code..

```
{
  "context": {
    "my_creds": {
      "user": "ssssssssssssssssss",
      "password": "sssssssssssssssssssssss"
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "values": [
          {
            "text": ""
          }
        ],
        "response_type": "text",
        "selection_policy": "sequential"
      }
    ]
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "ssssssssssss/user-detail",
      "type": "server",
      "parameters": {
        "name": "<?input.text?>",
        "lastname": "<?input.text?>"
      },
      "credentials": "$my_creds",
      "result_variable": "$my_result"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now my action user detail is giving response when i am invoking the code. [image]

But when i am checking the output with my chatbot I am getting execution of cloud functions action took too long.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a 5 second limitation on processing time for a cloud function being called from a dialog node. If your process will need longer than this, you'll need to do it client side through your application layer.